# javascript within php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to do the following in jquery

```
<?php

    echo "<script>";
    echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
    echo "$('#mainbody-wrapper').removeClass('mainbody-wrapper')";
    echo ";";
    echo "$('#mainbody-wrapper').addClass('newStyle')";

    echo ";";
    echo "contentHeight=$('.content').css('height') + 20";
    echo ";";

    echo "alert(contentHeight)";
    echo ";";
    echo "$('#mainbody-wrapper').css('height',contentHeight)";
    echo ";";
    echo "$('#subcontent-wrapper').remove()";
    echo ";";
    echo "})";
    echo "</script>";
```

?>

But the variable contentHeight output 300px20. I want to do javascript addition, but its getting concatenated. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Your problem isn't because of PHP; it's a pure JavaScript + jQuery problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parseInt():

```
 echo "contentHeight= parseInt($('.content').css('height')) + 20";
```

also to go to the next line, use line breaks `\n`.

example:

```
echo "contentHeight= parseInt($('.content').css('height')) + 20;\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to read the height, jquery has a [height](http://api.jquery.com/height) method

```
echo "contentHeight=$('.content').height() + 20";
```

From the doco:

> The difference between `.css('height')` and `.height()` is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The `.height()` method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to echo everything?  You know you can run php and javascript together in the same file.

for example:

```
<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>
<script>
jQuery("<?php echo $var; ?>").addClass("test");
</script>
<?php echo 'end'; ?>
```